# Python time.time() in PHP

Tags: python, php, time

In Python `time.time()` returns the timestamp associated with the current time to 6 decimal places and, in PHP, `microtime(true)` returns the current time to 4 decimal places. Is there any way I can get the current time to 6 decimal places in PHP? Thanks.

Python: 1632816181.314063

PHP: 1632816181.3140

Comment: In Python, `time.time()` returns a *floating-point* number, it doesn't have "6 decimals" or "4 decimals", but the number of decimals shown depends on the value of the number and on how you output it. I'm sure this is similar in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you try it this one I think working perfect according your required.**

```
<?php 
    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $timestamp = $now->getTimestamp();
    echo $data = $timestamp.".".$now->format("u");
    
    // Result :- 1632823152.201900
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Yep Bro @Lucilfer

Comment: I was interested and a bit suspicious how `createFromFormat()` would handle the microtime float value. It's a bit disapointing but it seems that PHP is truncating the float value and loosing some precision :-( But at least it always displays 6 digits (often padded with zeros).

Comment: Yeah I know always displays 6 digits because he's required after timestamp display microtime with 6 digits. He had checked on python programing so same as a display on php.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the impression that a floating number in PHP is displayed by default with the `echo` or `print` command without all the decimals you would like.

Use `printf()` or `sprintf()` with the `%f` specifier and add the number of digits you would like to have. In your case 6 digits would be `%.6f`:

```php
<?php

// Save the floating-point Unix timestamp just for comparing below.
$microtime = microtime(true);

echo 'echo $microtime            : ' . $microtime . "\n";
printf("printf(\"%%.6f\", \$microtime) : %.6f\n", $microtime);

// Some have proposed to create a DateTime instance.
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $microtime);
echo "DateTime::format('U.u')    : " . $datetime->format('U.u') . "\n";
```

This outputs the following:

```text
echo $microtime            : 1632834055.1038
printf("%.6f", $microtime) : 1632834055.103771
DateTime::format('U.u')    : 1632834055.103800
```

As one can see, it seems rather weird but PHP's *DateTime* class is kind of dropping some precision in the process somewhere. The resulting format of `u` seems to be padded with zeros at the end.

[Test the PHP code here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba036c3223d58932d3dc62fd3438b3bf877b5c76)

Comment: Yes, this works too but I just noticed that in python time.time() it sometime even returns with 7 or 5 decimals too, with printf() it will be fixed to 6 decimals and also with DateTime::format()

Comment: Yes, except that with *DateTime* we loose precision somehow :-/